# $.each functionality differs with object type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When my $.each statement looks like this:

```
 $.each($(".permissions"), function (index, element) {
... }).promise().done(function () {...});
```

it works.

When my $.each statement looks like this:

```
 $.each(dataObj, function (index, element) {

}.promise().done(function () {...});
```

returns the error:

**$.each.promise is not a function**

Why is that?  What can I do as a workaround?

There is an ajax script in the done function that I want to run only after the $.each to avoid a race condition.

Comment: `$.each` returns the object it was operating on.  So, whether or not there's a `.promise()` method depends on what you are calling `.$each` on.

Comment: Good insight, but I don't see how that'll help my problem.  That makes sense as to why its not working, but what would the alternative be?

Comment: The "problem" is that it has nothing to do with `$.each`.  Also, `$each` is synchronous, so I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Your first sample should not work... Or if it does, it isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: So you're saying that if there is a $.ajax call after the $.each there is no way for the $.ajax to run before the $.each is finished?  If that's the case make it an answer and I'll give you the points!

Comment: @Scottingham: That's correct.

Comment: @KevinB: It'll work, but the deferred will be immediately resolved, so the callback will run right away.

Comment: @KevinB: jQuery objects (like `$(".permissions")`) do have a `.promise()` method, but it serves no purpose.  It's immediately resolved.

Comment: @KevinB: Like I was trying to say earlier, `$.each` just returns whatever you called it with (`$.each($(".permissions")` *returns* `$(".permissions")`). So `$(".permissions").promise()` exists, but `[1,2,3].promise()` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `.promise()` here at all.  `$.each` is *synchronous*, so there will *never* be a "race condition" here.  The code will not continue until `$.each` is finished.

Just run the `$.ajax` call when the `$.each` is done.

```
$.each(dataObj, function (index, element) {
});
$.ajax({});
```